# Make Blender recalculate non-faceweighted normals?

Tags: normals

Seems like a silly question but I've been trying to have blender generate normals without weighting the faces into it, in order to then extrude along normals. At the moment, it seems like Blender is grabbing the normals of all faces around the vertex and multiplying with face size to get the vertex normal. I'd like a simple average, to result in a 45 angle at a 90 face junction. Can I do that automatically?

[image: Weighted normals]

Should be pretty clear what I mean from the image - the normals closer to the camera are tilted more towards the normal of the face that goes off-screen, which is larger. I'd like them to be a simple average, which would be bisecting the angle between the faces.

Comment: you're showing _vertex_ normals, not _face_ normals. are you saying you wish th extrude (what?) along those vertex normals, but you wish they were not weighted?

Comment: Let's not focus on what I'm trying to do with the normals. I want *vertex* normals to be the average of *face* normals, without accounting for face size. That's it.

For completeness's sake though, I'm using the Extrude Region (Vertex Normals) to get a consistent edge around the model. With those vertex normals, it's extruding more on the large side and less on the small side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems you wish something that the solidify modifier maybe can do easily:

[image]

which after enabling viewport display gets:

[image]

You can use vertex group to partially apply.

Surely your project is more complicated and different, but since not much of it was shown above...

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite what I need, although it's on the right track. I have an already manifold mesh (as in, it has volume that I just want to add to) of apartment walls. I added an edge loop to separate out the baseboard and would like to just select everything and extrude along normals. As you can see, the vertex normals I get by default are not the ones I'd need to get a baseboard. Solidify sorta does the trick but creates a bunch of extra geometry I need to remove. :/

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion, splitting off the faces I wanted to extrude into a separate object and then applying the solidify modifier. Worked out pretty decent, thanks